# MySQL query to get count of column name from a table of a database?

Tags: mysql

Can anybody please convert this SQL query to mysql syntax:-

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM DataBaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName';
```

This is the SQL query to get no of records in a column of a table in a database.

I want the MySQL syntax of above query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This query looks OK to me for MySQL.  What error do you get when running this?

Comment: SELECT Count(Id) FROM DBName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName'' at line 2 0.000 sec

Comment: Thie above one is  the error i am getting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
```

Comment: It is throwing unknown column name error .But the column name exists in that DB/Table